What does shuffle intermediate buffer on the Map side mean?
I am trying to understand Spark memory management and I came across this blog. In that the author mentions one of the usages of Execution memory in Spark:

For example,it is used to store hash table for hash aggregation step, it is used to store shuffle intermediate buffer on the Map side in memory etc,.


What does shuffle intermediate buffer mean and what is it used for?
What does Map side mean?

